# Position in an Angular.js collection

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have this collection/array of objects

```
$scope.users = [
    {name:'Maria', score:90},
    {name:'Bob', score:10},
    {name:'Claire', score:17},
];
$scope.currentUser = 'Bob';
```

I list them using ng-repeat and an orderBy

```
li.list-group-item(ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'score':true")
```

How can I show a message saying: "**Welcome Bob, today you are #3**".
Where "1,2,3..." is his position in that ordered collection based on "score"

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat, you might be able to use the `$index` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find current user by using $filter

JavaScript

```
app.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.users = [
        {name: 'Maria', score: 90},
        {name: 'Bob', score: 10},
        {name: 'Claire', score: 17},
    ];

    user = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {name: 'Bob'})[0];
    // or
    // user = $filter('filter')($scope.users, name: $scope.currentUser)[0];

    $scope.position = $scope.users.indexOf(user) + 1;
}]);
```

Template

```
<p>Welcome {{ currentUser }}, today you are #{{ position }}</p>
```

Should work.

Comment: Actually before getting the indexOf you should do a `$filter('orderBy')($scope.users, '-score')`. But thank you; it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{$index}}` to show the index.

Remember it starts at 0 so you have to add 1.

```
{{ $index + 1 }}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how can I read that {{ $index }} from outside of the ng-repeat? On my Controller I use `$scope.welcomeMessage = 'Welcome' + $scope.currentUser + ', today you are...'`